# Expression Engine Importer(solspace) scheduled cron jobs don't update entry

Tags: solspace-importer

I scheduled the import job using curl, but it doesn't update the entries. If I visit the link in browser, it works fine.

Comment: As written, what you posted above is not a question. Please post an answerable question. Also, post more detail about what you have tried on your end that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your crontask isn't configured correctly.

1) Verify your curl statement works properly by running it in Terminal (Mac) or Putty (Windows).

and

2) Verify you're configuring your crontask correctly. Are you storing it in the right file (or configuring it correctly in Plesk?). Consult your hosting company if need-be.